# Matrix Multiplication - When do you only multiply by one number and add vs. multiplying all numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

*I wasn't sure where to put this. Just let me know if I should delete it or if there is another category/website where this question would fit better. Thanks! Or if you know the answer & don't think it fits, just let me know and I can delete it.

Okay, so the first question of this type I saw is below.

[image]

The explanation says to multiply each number of students by the ratio of sports awards. Easy and understandable.

This is the first question I have ever seen with matrix multiplication, so I assumed that this was just how it works. However, upon seeing this second question..

[image]

I understand how you come to each answer, but under general circumstances, should you use the first question's method (i.e. multiplying first # to top, second # to second, etc.) or the second's (i.e. multiplying each # by each number in the second pair of brackets) or does it depend on where the sets of brackets fall/how the question is worded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is calculating
$$\begin{bmatrix}40 & 60 & 80 & 80\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0.3 \\ 0.4 \\ 0.2 \\ 0.5\end{bmatrix}$$
which is a $1 \times 4$ matrix times a $4 \times 1$ matrix, so the result is a $1 \times 1$ matrix (scalar).

The second is calculating 
$$\begin{bmatrix}a \\ 2a \\ 3a \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$
which is a $3 \times 1$ matrix times a $1 \times 3$ matrix, so the result is a $3 \times 3$ matrix.

In the second problem, there is no ambiguity because the problem tells you what product to calculate.

In the first problem, if you were unsure which matrix should go on the left and which should go on the right, you can easily rule out one possibility since all the answers are scalars. So you know you need to put the $1 \times 4$ matrix on the left, not on the right.

In general:

row vector $\times$ column vector = scalar

column vector $\times$ row vector = matrix

assuming the dimensions are compatible, meaning that if we want to multiply two matrices in this order: ($a \times b$)($c \times d$), then $b$ must equal $c$, or the product is undefined. The result will be $a \times d$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is definitely going to stay in my notes.